# How to pass input to a function in Nuxt3 and adjust it's width?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3

I want to execute the following function in Nuxt3

```
<script setup>
    function adjustWidth(input) {
        var value = input.value;
        var width = value.length * 8 + 25;
        input.style.width = width + "px";
    }
</script>
```

I am trying to do it like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="base-input">
       <input
       @keydown="adjustWidth(this)"
       type="text" 
       placeholder="Input title" 
       name="title"
       />
    </div>
</div>
```

Why am I unable to execute this correctly?

When I inspect the error it says:

```
caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

Because `input.value` appears to be `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codes inside your `adjustWidth` function are incorrect.

Reason why your code is not working is because you did not add a `v-model` on your input.

Try this, it should be working

```js
<script setup>
const inputVal = ref(200);
function adjustWidth(event) {
  event.target.style.width = `${inputVal.value}px`;
}
</script>
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="base-input">
      <input
        v-model="inputVal"
        @input="adjustWidth"
        type="number"
        placeholder="Input title"
        name="title"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

[Working example here](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNpdkM1OwzAQhF9lZSG1PTSpOEKK4MgLwMWHusmWGvlP9jqlivLubJIGot42801GM+7EWwhFm1E8iSrVUQeChJTDi3TaBh8JuoinHk7RW1ixcfUsXe1dItAuZPpQBvbAlvXjbrdhdsquJu0dqOY7J/rUDZ3X2KKjDXTSAYx3QSp+IRWJrgaLy2DimMNDN4cWrTIZ+/Bz4Mxeuqqc2nGvitAGowj5Bqga3UJtVEp7KaK/SDHKd+CoEm7H7D/Ojkm4fQG0W+sbNGyfW0jxT19HkeFi2JLTNSBTl+0R4xJw1xrP3jQYmb8PKUCaDC5NTtnh7zu9nLeUPGaae7uqcvEKov8FPEKWnw==)

Comment: Thank you. With some small adjustments I managed to do what I wanted. The problem was not in the `v-model`. I managed to get what I wanted trough `event.target.value.length`